# how to add one month in a raw date coming from oracle using PHP only?

Tags: php, oracle

Let's say I have this date, e.g.:

```
12-DEC-14 11.55.51.000000000 AM
```

and then I assigned it to variable, let's say:

```
$date = '12-DEC-14 11.55.51.000000000 AM';
```

Now the question is, how do I add 1 month or 2 months or so to that `$date` using only
php, without using any oracle sql date functions, just pure php, 
because I will save the result to oracle db table in that same format.

The result should be like, e.g.:

```
$nextmonth = '12-JAN-15 11.55.51000000000 AM';
```

Then that's the time I can save that `$nextmonth` in the table column. So how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` classes in this case, load that date and define its format. Then after creating the datetime object, adjust it to your x number of months, then present it again with the original format.

```
$input = '12-DEC-14 11.55.51.000000000 AM';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-y h.i.s A', $input);
$next_month = clone $date;
$next_month->modify('+1 month');
echo strtoupper($next_month->format('d-M-y h.i.s A'));
```

Comment: how bout the succeeding 9 zeroes ?, won't that cause any errors in oracle if I just append it like e.g `echo strtoupper($next_month->format('d-M-y h.i.s.000000000 A'));`

Comment: @sasori of course you can do that also, whats the column data type anyway?

Comment: it's a `TIMESTAMP(6)` , but the format is exactly like this inside that column `12-DEC-14 11.55.51.000000000 AM`

Comment: @sasori i don't know if that fractional seconds will bear its weight on insertion, but have you tried it?

Comment: not yet, am still building my code,I will test the saving of data later. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably only a very long comment rather than a real answer, but some of your comments let me think we have an instance of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here:

> it's a TIMESTAMP(6) , but the format is exactly like this inside that column 12-DEC-14 11.55.51.000000000 AM
>
> how bout the succeeding 9 zeroes ?, won't that cause any errors in oracle if I just append it like e.g echo strtoupper($next_month->format('d-M-y h.i.s.000000000 A'));

A `TIMESTAMP(6)` store a date-time information (a "point in time"). It hasn't any "format" par se. `TIMESTAMP` are great data type, as they allow you to easily perform calculation on data and time with a great precision at DB level such as *"adding one month"*.

*But*, without explicit request from your part, a *default format* is used to convert *timestamps* from and to *strings*.

*Maybe* your real issue is that Oracle try to *implicitly* convert your *string* to *timestamp* using its *standard* format. Usually, it is a far better idea to *explicitly* convert data type yourself. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#sthref324):

> Oracle recommends that you specify explicit conversions, rather than rely on implicit or automatic conversions, for these reasons:
>
> - [...]
> - implicit conversion depends on the context in which it occurs and may not work the same way in every case. For example, implicit conversion from a datetime value to a VARCHAR2 value may return an unexpected year depending on the value of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter.

Please note that above statement is true for `TIMESTAMP` too, as the "standard" format is user-definable using [`NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams132.htm#REFRN10131).

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php) has a similar warning:

> DATE columns are returned as strings formatted to the current date format. The default format can be changed with Oracle environment variables such as NLS_LANG or by a previously executed ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT command.

As a personal suggestion, I would say that you should never rely on *implicit* date/timestamp conversion, as any change of the relevant configuration settings at DB-level or for the current session will break your code.

---

So, depending the way you insert your value, using an explicit format might be as simple as wrapping the bind variable in a proper `TO_TIMESTAMP(....)` call:

```
// query the original data
$q = oci_parse ($connection ,
                "INSERT INTO ....
                        VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP(:date_as_str, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF'), other_columns...)");


$q = oci_parse ($connection ,
                "INSERT INTO ....
                        VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP(:date_as_str, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF'), other_columns...)");
```

Coming back to your initial question: *"how to add one month in a raw date"* *" I will save the result to oracle db table in that same <strike>format</strike> data type"* , this should be as simple as adding 1 month when inserting the value:

```
$q = oci_parse ($connection ,
                "INSERT INTO ....
                        VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP(:date_as_str, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF')
                                + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, other_columns...)");
```